# Postman showing: Invalid JSON payload received. Expected a value

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

Postman showing: Invalid JSON payload received. Expected a value while sending Firebase Push Notification using Postman.

Also I have sent valid JSON.

```
{
  "message": {
    "topic": "all-notifications",
    "data": {
      "image":"some image link",
      "link": "my app link was here",
      "title": "Hey what",
      "message": "This is message!"
    }
  }
}
```

Postman returning:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected a value.\n \"Hey what\",\r\n      \"m\n^",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Also, if I remove "title" from my body, it will show same for message.

Following is my Firebase Messaging class:

```
class FirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        private var NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.zyrosite.nikunjgarg"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 100
    }

    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        var title: String? = null
        var messageBody: String? = null
        //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
        val imageUri: String? = remoteMessage.data["image"]
        val link: String? = remoteMessage.data["link"]

        Log.i("HEHEHEHH", link.toString())

        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            title = remoteMessage.data["title"]
            messageBody = remoteMessage.data["message"]
        } else {
            title = remoteMessage.notification!!.title
            messageBody = remoteMessage.notification!!.body
        }

        //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri)
        try {
            showNotification(context = applicationContext, title, messageBody, bitmap, link)
        } catch(e:Exception) {
            Log.i("haha", e.message.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages()
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        Log.e(Constants.TAG,"New Token: $token")
    }

    private fun showNotification(context: Context, title: String?, messageBody: String?, image: Bitmap?, link: String?) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("custom://" + System.currentTimeMillis())
        intent.action = "actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis()
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        intent.putExtra("LINK", link)
        val pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        val notification: Notification
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
            )
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setLargeIcon(image) /*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .build()
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
            ) as NotificationManager
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                title,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            try {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            } catch (e:Exception) {
                Log.i("hehe", "yups" + e.message.toString())
            }
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        } else {
            notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
            )
                .setLargeIcon(image) /*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .build()
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
            ) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        }
    }

    private fun isUrlValid(url: String?): Boolean {
        return try {
            val obj = URL(url)
            obj.toURI()
            true
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            false
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            false
        }
    }

    private fun getBitmapfromUrl(imageUrl: String?): Bitmap? {
        if (isUrlValid(imageUrl)) {
            return try {
                val url = URL(imageUrl)
                val connection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.doInput = true
                connection.connect()
                val input: InputStream = connection.inputStream
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("hehehhehe", e.message.toString())
                null
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

I have added oAuth 2.0 token in Authorisation as well and Content-Type as application/json.